# How to use different colors for each selected row int Primeng table

Tags: angular, html-table, primeng

I am using the new p-table component of primeng and I would like to use different colors for the selected rows in the table on button click.
There are many different buttons and each of them should select some rows but each in a different color. e.g. Red-Button selects 10 rows and highlights them in red. Green--button highlights another 5 rows green. The selections should persist in the table with their corresponding background color if a new button is clicked.

Are there any hidden tricks in primeng to do this?

Columns are generated dynamically.

```
<p-table #dt [value]="data" [resizableColumns]="true" [columns]="header"
  [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30]"
  sortMode="multiple" [reorderableColumns]="true" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedRows">
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <div style="text-align:left;" class="ui-g">
      <p-multiSelect [options]="selectedColumns" [(ngModel)]="header" selectedItemsLabel="{0} columns selected" [style]="{minWidth: '200px'}"
        defaultLabel="Choose Columns"></p-multiSelect>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns" style="width:150px" pResizableColumn pReorderableColumn [pSortableColumn]="column">
        {{column}}
        <p-sortIcon [field]="column"></p-sortIcon>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">
        <input pInputText type="text" style="width:130px" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="data" [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex">
      <td *ngFor="let column of columns" style="width:150px;padding:0 5px 0 5px;line-height: 1;">{{data[column]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: Are the buttons outside the table ? Can you create a Plunker please ?

Comment: yes the buttons are outside of table.

Comment: Can you share your typescript code please ?

Comment: @Antikhippe The Component just holds arrays for columns, data and the selections nothing special.

Comment: It would help us not to write it ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

```
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-car>
    <tr [style.background]="car.selected == 'true' ? car.color : ''">
      <td>{{car.vin}}</td>
      <td>{{car.year}}</td>
      <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
      <td>{{car.color}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
```

You can conditional bind the row background color and add the "selected" property in the button event.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nex5cC?p=preview)